# How to remove html added with jquery after DOM is loaded?

Tags: jquery, html

after something i execute this code:

```
function checkUser(value){
        $('#user').removeClass('has-error');
        $('#user div').on(function(){
            $('#user div').remove('label');
        });
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "",
          data: { user: value }
        }).done(function(msg) {
            if(msg == " userexist"){
                $('#user').addClass('has-error');
                $('#user div input').before('<label class="control-label" for="usuario" id="erro">Usuário já existe, escolha outro.</label>');
            }
        });
    }
```

this work, but the problem is to remove this code:

```
<label class="control-label" for="usuario" id="erro">Usuário já existe, escolha outro.</label>
```

I need to remove its before the `function checkUser(value)` is executed, i tryed to to use this code but i dont know how to remove. This code is not executed by something clicked or selected, i think i have problen to fire on().

```
$('#user').removeClass('has-error');
$('#user div').on(function(){
    $('#user div').remove('label');
});
```

this work `$('#user').removeClass('has-error');` but this dont work:

```
$('#user div').on(function(){
    $('#user div').remove('label');
});
```

I tryed to understand the api from on() and I saw that you can use custom events but i dont know how to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is    `$('#user div').remove('label');`, when you pass a selector to `.remove()` method it filters the collection and removes matching elements, the collection has only DIV elements, so the `.remove()` silently fails.

```
$('#user div label').remove();
```

If you want to listen to the events of the dynamically generated elements you should delegate the event, the target element of delegation must be a static element.

```
$('#staticParent').on('event', '#theGeneratedElement', function() {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: this worked for me! thanks
I changed the:
$('#user div').on(function(){
    $('#user div').remove('label');
});

to $('#user div label').remove(); and worked

Comment: i just need to wait more 4minutes to accept your answer...stackoverflow policy

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs...](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

To trigger a custom event

```
$( "#some-element").trigger( "custom");
```

Then:

```
$('#user div').on('custom', function(){
    $('#user div').remove('label');
});
```